# When I try to push an element to a array but it takes only one rest of the elements are got removed automatically. It happen when use useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState([]);
let brandList = [];
const handleCheckBox = (e) => {
    const { value, checked } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
      brandList.push(value);
    } else {
      let ind = brandList.indexOf(value);
      brandList.splice(ind, 1);
    }
   
    console.log(brandList);
    setFilter([...brandList]);
  };
```

When I try to push an element to an array but it takes only one rest of the elements are got removed automatically. It happens when I using the useState hook.

Please checkout the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`brandList` is redeclared an empty array each render cycle. This is why you only ever see that last filter item value added.

Use the `filter` state directly.

Example:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState([]);

const handleCheckBox = (e) => {
  const { value, checked } = e.target;
  if (checked) {
    setFilter(filter => [...filter, value]);
  } else {
    setFilter(filter => filter.filter(el => el !== value));
  }
};
```